# fadein and fadeout jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function()
{
    function animation()
    {
        $('#img0').attr('src',$('#img1').attr('src')).fadeOut(4000).attr('src',$('#img2').attr('src')).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000).attr('src',$('#img3').attr('src')).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000) ;
        animation();
    }
});
</script>

<body>
<img  id="img0" width="613" height="260" alt="OffLease Only Lot" />
<img src="static/images/home/slides/SLIDERS-mP.jpg" id="img1" width="613" height="260" alt="OffLease Only Lot" hidden="true" />
<img src="static/images/home/slides/slider_usa.jpg" id="img2"  width="613" height="260" alt="OffLease Only Lot" hidden="true" />
<img src="static/images/home/slides/SLIDERS-ODOMETER.jpg"  id="img3"  width="613" height="260" alt="OffLease Only Lot" hidden="true" />

</body>
</html>
```

i want slide showing the images by changing the source of image and proceed by appearing and disappearing it.
but my code didn't work

- why?
- how can i fix it?

Comment: **JsFiddle it.**
[Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: first of all - ask yourself where/how do you fire `animation()` function? All i see you have defined function `animiate()`. And in this function i see recursion, so `animation()` will fire `animation()`, then `animation()` will fire `animation()` and so on...

Comment: You've put the key to the box inside the box and locked it. Also, not sure your box is the best box I've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to cycle the three images, do something like this:

```
function animate1() {
    $('#img1').fadeIn(4000, function() {
        $('#img1').fadeOut(4000, animate2);
    })
}

function animate2() {
    // Do the same thing here, and do animate3 too
}

$(function() { $('#img0').fadeOut(4000, animate1) };
```

I would also take a minute to go over the jQuery fadeOut and fadeIn pages. I don't think they work the way you think they work.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: i replaced by this : `$(function() { $('#img0').fadeOut(4000, animate1); });

     function animate1(){$('#img0').attr('src',$('#img1').attr('src')).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000, animate2());}
  function animate2(){$('#img0').attr('src',$('#img2').attr('src')).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000, animate3());}
  function animate3(){$('#img0').attr('src',$('#img3').attr('src')).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000, animate1());} ` but this error is logged `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for an animation to finish first like this...

```
element$.fadeOut(4000, function () {

  // Do something when faded out

  element$.fadeIn(4000, function () {

    // Do something when faded in

  });
});
```

Comment: i replaced it by `<script >
$(function(){
     
     $('#img0').attr('src',$('#img1').attr('src')).fadeOut(4000, function(){console.log("hi");}).attr('src',$('#img2').attr('src')).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000, function(){console.log("hi");}).attr('src',$('#img3').attr('src')).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000, function(){console.log("hi");}) ;
 });

</script>` but the same result